# Move SD card from Raspberry Pi 2 to Raspberry Pi 4 Model B

Tags: raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, raid

Simple/not simple question: is it safe to move the SD card from my existing Raspberry Pi 2 (Model B Rev 1.1) to the latest-and-greatest version? The existing Pi is running Raspbian Bullseye and a 4 drive mdadm RAID 5- hence wanting to upgrade to the more capable board. I figure it's easier to move the existing SD card + drives to the faster Pi than to set up the new Pi from scratch and migrate the RAID to it.

Thoughts?

Comment: yes, it is safe